# how to convert html webpage to pdf by clicking save page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pdf

I have a webpage of around 30 pages consisting of some text, pictures and videos. When the user click save page button, he will get the option of saving in pdf but it is not giving the proper alignment and looks different as it looks in the original webpage. I am trying to save it in the landscape and portraits but its not giving the same feel and looks as the original webpage looks. 
I was also trying to wkhtmltopdf via linux terminal, its giving the following error:
Loading page (1/2)
Warning: SSL error ignored
Error: Authentication Required

What should I do to get the pdf while saving it exactly as I see in the webpage (including portraits and landscapes)?

Comment: What does "portrait" and "landscape" mean for a (resizeable!) webpage? Save screen shots of the web page in the PDF. Or build "nice" PDFs off-line and let the user download those. Webpages and PDFs are sufficiently different to make an *exact* copy not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible in HTML / CSS / JS. All you can do is a print version of your webpage (with Media Queries). 
You'll need a server-side lib to generate the PDF.